# Where to put text properties?

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, spring-mvc

I'm trying to do localization for my Java web application and I am getting an error. I am using Maven for dependencies and I am using Google app engine (Jetty web server). The application is using spring framework. Here is what I have so far:

**Project structure:**

[image]

**messages_en_US.properties**

```
label.firstname=First Name
label.lastname=Last Name
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="t" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<t:genericpage>
    <jsp:attribute name="title">
      Welcome
    </jsp:attribute>
    <jsp:body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/index.js"></script>
        <div class="flex_container_column">
            <spring:message code="label.firstname" />
            <br>
            <spring:message code="label.lastname" />
            <br>
        </div>
    </jsp:body>
</t:genericpage>
```

**spring-mvc-servlet.xml**

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<!-- Resource bundle message: Start -->
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
</bean>

<bean id="handlerMapping"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
    </property>
</bean>
<!-- Resource bundle message: End -->
```

**Error**

```
WARNING: Nested in javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'label.firstname' for locale 'en_US'.:
javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'label.firstname' for locale 'en_US'.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.MessageTag.doEndTag(MessageTag.java:200)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspx_meth_spring_005fmessage_005f0(index_jsp.java:110)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp.access$0(index_jsp.java:97)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp$Helper.invoke1(index_jsp.java:176)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp$Helper.invoke(index_jsp.java:205)
```

**pom.xml**

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**I tried few things:**

1. Moved the messages to `/WEB-INF` but I got the same error when I changed `<property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/messages" />`. But as per my understanding, if I do so, then I might not be able to access this in the code. That is why I put it into resources initially.
2. I removed en_US from the default messages property file name, but I got the same error.

Appreciate your help on where and how to setup the project property files + the text.properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up putting the `messages.properties` in `/WebContent/WEB-INF/messages/messages.properties` and the reason I was getting the error was because I have 2 contexts defined:

1. applicationContext.xml
2. spring-mvc-servlet.xml

I was putting the configuration in `spring-mvc-servlet.xml`, which was not the right place. Instead, it should have been in `applicationContext.xml` (the parent context). I solved the issue but then I faced another problem, `LocaleChangeInterceptor` is not intercepting, so the language can't be changed! However, the problem is resolved.